# DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I updated my rails 5.1.4 app to 5.2.0. I have the following scope in one of my models:

```
  scope :by_category, lambda { |category_slug|
    category_ids = Category.find_by(slug: category_slug)&.subtree_ids
    where(category_id: category_ids)
  }
```

Rails returns me following error because of that scope:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "coalesce(\"categories\".\"ancestry\", '')". Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.0. This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql()
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: what does `subtree_ids`?

Comment: This is method from ancestry gem: https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that the [`ordered_by_ancestry` scope](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/blob/master/lib/ancestry/has_ancestry.rb#L47):

```
scope :ordered_by_ancestry, Proc.new { |order|
  if %w(mysql mysql2 sqlite sqlite3 postgresql).include?(connection.adapter_name.downcase) && ActiveRecord::VERSION::MAJOR >= 5
    reorder("coalesce(#{connection.quote_table_name(table_name)}.#{connection.quote_column_name(ancestry_column)}, '')", order)
  else
    reorder("(CASE WHEN #{connection.quote_table_name(table_name)}.#{connection.quote_column_name(ancestry_column)} IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), #{connection.quote_table_name(table_name)}.#{connection.quote_column_name(ancestry_column)}", order)
  end
}
```

is passing a raw string of SQL to `#reorder` and, as the warning states, this is deprecated in Rails 5.2 (and will be removed altogether in Rails 6).

A [pull request](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/pull/384) was just submitted which fixes this by wrapping those strings in `Arel.sql` calls. I'd expect this to merged quickly (despite the pull request missing an `Arel.sql` call in the second branch) but in the mean time, you have some options:

1. Ignore the warning and wait for the gem to be patched.
2. Fork the gem, merge the pull request, and use your forked version until the gem merges the pull request in question.
3. Manually replace the `ordered_by_ancestry` scope:

   ```
   def self.ordered_by_ancestry(order)
     reorder(Arel.sql("coalesce(#{connection.quote_table_name(table_name)}.#{connection.quote_column_name(ancestry_column)}, '')"), order)
   end
   ```

   and wait for the pull request to get merged.

---

**UPDATE**: The pull request which fixes this warning was [just merged](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/pull/384#event-1580305654) so there's no need to wait anymore, you should be able to grab the latest from GitHub and get on with more interesting things. Thanks to [kbrock](https://github.com/kbrock) for sorting this out.